# Zen - cart, google wallet integration with states list

Tags: zen-cart, android-pay

I have a problem with the integration of google checkout in zencart using the google checkout contribution.
http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=206
The main problem here is that google keeps returning the error.

"Error parsing XML; message from parser is: Invalid value for body of allowed-areas in checkout-shopping-cart/checkout-flow-support/merchant-checkout-flow-support/shipping-methods/flat-rate-shipping/shipping-restrictions: Must be a U.S. 2-letter postal code or state name"

Below is an extract of one of the payment methods with the problem, I don't know and can't figure out what's wrong. Any help will be really appreciated.

Forgive my bad English.

```
    <flat-rate-shipping name="Table: Vary by Weight/Price">
      <price currency="USD">0</price>
      <shipping-restrictions>
        <allow-us-po-box>false</allow-us-po-box>
        <allowed-areas>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AL</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AS</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AZ</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AR</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AE</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AM</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>AP</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>CA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>CO</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>CT</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>DE</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>DC</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>FL</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>GA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>ID</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>IL</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>IN</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>IA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>KS</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>KY</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>LA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>ME</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MH</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MD</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MI</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MN</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MS</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MO</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MT</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NE</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NV</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NH</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NJ</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NM</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NY</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>NC</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>ND</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>MP</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>OH</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>OK</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>OR</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>PA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>RI</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>SC</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>SD</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>TN</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>TX</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>UT</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>VT</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>VI</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>VA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>WA</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>WV</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>WI</state>
          </us-state-area>
          <us-state-area>
            <state>WY</state>
          </us-state-area>
        </allowed-areas>
      </shipping-restrictions>
    </flat-rate-shipping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer - I'm not a Zen dev/user.

I suspect it has to do with the Armed forces State Codes. See if removing them fixes the error.

However, it's probably better to use either

- [`us-country-area`](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Flat_Rate_Shipping#tag_us-country-area), or,
- instead of listing States where you do ship, define States where you *don't* with [`excluded-areas`](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Tag_Reference#tag_excluded-areas)

Hth...